# AngularJS validation message and showing no results and results div issue on submit

Tags: html, angularjs

The following form shows a list of data on submit. I am trying to show no results found when there is no data on submit. I tried like shown below,it shows and hides the div. But when there is no options selected on form and click submit button it shows the no result div.How to show the no results div only when form validation succeeds and there is no data to display.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group" >
   <label class="radio-inline"> 
    <input name="sampleinlineradio" value="3" type="radio" ng-model="radioption"  
              ng-required="!radioption"> MAIN 1</label> 
   <label class="radio-inline"> 
   <input name="sampleinlineradio" value="1" type="radio"  ng-model="radioption"  >
        Main 2</label>

 <div ng-show="!radioption && buttonClicked">Please select one.</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <label ng-repeat="branch in branches"> 
   <input type="checkbox" name="selectedBranches[]" value="{{branch.value}}" 
          ng-model="branch.selected" ng-required="isOptionsRequired()" >
    {{branch.name}}</label>  

<div ng-show="isOptionsRequired() && buttonClicked">Please select one.</div>
</div>

<input type="button" ng-click="fetchresults()" value="submit" >

<div ng-show="buttonClicked">
    <table>  <thead>.....</thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr ng-show="results.length!=0"  ng-repeat="r in results">
       <td></td></tbody></table>
</div>

<div ng-show="buttonClicked"> 
<span ng-show="results.length==0 ">No results.</span> 
</div>
```

Minimal Controller Code

```
$scope.fetchresults = function(){
    $scope.results = Result.query({main: $scope.radioption, branch: $scope.selection[0], }); 
$scope.buttonClicked = true;
}
```

**EDIT:**
I used model to validate and $valid is also working, as suggested below.But Got a couple of glitches. If i click the button it does not show div. but after validation is over it shows automatically "no results" from the click before. How to stop this.And while it lists data when its available it shows "no results" for a second or so

Comment: try to pass radio model in click if the model is null or empty then show form validation and in else case  show no results found if u don't have resuts

Comment: Can you check the below answer?

Comment: Yes thanks. Checking now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the below snippet, I have changed most of them in angular way with `$invalid`, `$pristine`, `$submitted` and `$valid`.

You can check the angular documentation to read about them.

[Link 1](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms), [Link 2](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form)

**Note**: You can use a `submit` button and get rid of `ng-click` event and use `ng-submit` instead which can't be used in this snippet as form submit is not allowed. Comment the line `form.$submitted = true;` when you use a `submit` button.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('TestController', function($scope){
  $scope.isFieldInvalid = function(field) {
     var form = $scope.testForm;
     return form[field].$invalid && (!form[field].$pristine || form.$submitted);
  };
  
  $scope.fetchResults = function(){
    var form = $scope.testForm;
    form.$submitted = true;  // comment this line if button type="submit"
    if(form.$valid){
      $scope.searching = true;
    
      $scope.results = [];
    
      var rnd = Math.random();
    
      if(rnd >= 0.5) {
        $scope.results = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}];
      }
      
      //$scope.results = Result.query({main: $scope.radioption,        branch: $scope.selection[0], });
      
      $scope.buttonClicked = true;
      $scope.searching = false; 
      
    }
    
   };
  
});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form name="testForm" ng-controller="TestController" ng-submit="fetchResults()" role="form" novalidate="">
<div class="form-group" ng-controller="TestController">
   <label class="radio-inline"> 
    <input name="sampleinlineradio" value="3" type="radio" ng-model="radioption" ng-required="true"> MAIN 1</label> 
   <label class="radio-inline"> 
   <input name="sampleinlineradio" value="1" type="radio"  ng-model="radioption" ng-required="true"  >
        Main 2</label>

 <div ng-show="isFieldInvalid('sampleinlineradio')">Please select one.</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <label ng-repeat="branch in branches"> 
   <input type="checkbox" name="selectedBranches[]" value="{{branch.value}}" 
          ng-model="branch.selected" ng-required="isOptionsRequired()" >
    {{branch.name}}</label>  

<div ng-show="isOptionsRequired() && buttonClicked">Please select one.</div>
</div>

<input type="button" value="submit" ng-click="fetchResults()" >

<div ng-show="buttonClicked && !searching">
    <table>  <thead></thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr ng-show="results.length!=0"  ng-repeat="r in results">
       <td>{{r.id}}</td></tbody></table>
</div>

<div ng-show="buttonClicked && !searching"> 
<span ng-show="results.length==0 ">No results.</span> 
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried the whole day to do like this. but it did not work. that is why tried like in question. Dude actually your way help me understand things. Thank you so much for your time and effort.

Comment: When there is data available to list, "no results" shows up for a second when i click. I tried using display:none; but it did not work. Is there a way to stop it.

Comment: Can you upload your code in your question. I have to check your approach.

Comment: Actually the form have some more part and i could not validate it using $valid and $submitted as you suggested. So for time being i followed my old way and made it work using your inputs. Now just that flickering issue. Should i post as different question or update my approach here?

Comment: Can you post as different question, since we don't want to make this thread going longer. We can start fresh with your current approach.

Comment: Okay will post and let you know soon. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40800716/angularjs-hidden-div-visible-when-clicking)

Answer (score 1):

Give your form a name

```
<form name="formName">
```

Then you can do

```
ng-show="results.length==0 && formName.$valid"
```

[Some more information on angularJS form validation](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation)

Comment: I have got a form name. missed it here while i am making code minimal. sorry. I used model to validate and $valid is also working.But Got a couple of glitches. If a click the button it does not show div. but after validation is over it shows automatically "no result" from the click before. How to stop this.And while it lists data when its available it shows "no result" for a second or so.