# AngularJS ng-repeat 'No Results' div visibility flickering on second button click

Tags: angularjs

The following form shows a list of data on submit. I am trying to show no results found when there is no data on submit. It works okay. But when there is data available to list, "no results" shows up for a second when i click. I tried using display:none; but it did not work. How to stop it from showing.

HTML

```
<form class="form-inline" name="myForm" >
<div class="form-group" >
   <label class="radio-inline"> 
    <input name="sampleinlineradio" value="3" type="radio" ng-model="radioption"  
              ng-required="!radioption"> MAIN 1</label> 
   <label class="radio-inline"> 
   <input name="sampleinlineradio" value="1" type="radio"  ng-model="radioption"  >
        Main 2</label>

 <div ng-show="!radioption && buttonClicked">Please select one.</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <label ng-repeat="branch in branches"> 
   <input type="checkbox" name="selectedBranches[]" value="{{branch.value}}" 
          ng-model="branch.selected" ng-required="isOptionsRequired()" >
    {{branch.name}}</label>  

<div ng-show="isOptionsRequired() && buttonClicked">Please select one.</div>
</div>

<div>
<label class="searchlabel"> 
 <input type="radio" name="searchradio1" value="showComponentSearch"  ng-model="value"  
    ng-required="value == 'showComponentSearch'" > 
Search By Component</label> 
 <input type="text" name="comptext" ng-model="search" id="tags" 
    ng-required = "value == 'showComponentSearch' && search == 'comptext'" >

<div ng-show="value == 'showComponentSearch' && !search && buttonClicked">Please enter text before submit.</div>

<div>
<label class="searchlabel">
<input name="searchradio2" value="showDateRangeSearch" type="radio" ng-model="value" 
    ng-required="value == 'showDateRangeSearch'" > 
Search By Time</label>
</div>  </div>
<div ng-show="!value && buttonClicked">Please select one search option.</div>

<input type="button" ng-click="fetchresults()" value="submit" >
</form>

<div ng-show="buttonClicked">
    <table>  <thead>.....</thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr ng-show="results.length!=0"  ng-repeat="r in results">
       <td></td></tbody></table>
</div>

<div ng-show="buttonClickedAgain"> 
<span ng-show="results.length==0 ">No results.</span> 
</div>
```

In Controller

```
$scope.fetchresults = function(){
   if($scope.searchSelectionValue == 'showComponentSearch') {
        $scope.results = Result.query({main: $scope.radioption, branch: $scope.selection[0],
            component:$scope.search }); 
   if($scope.search) { 
     $scope.buttonClickedAgain = true;
        }
    }
$scope.buttonClicked = true;
};
```

Comment: Can you try the below answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding the line `$scope.buttonClickedAgain = false;` before the `if` statement as below.

```
$scope.fetchresults = function(){
        $scope.buttonClickedAgain = false;
   if($scope.searchSelectionValue == 'showComponentSearch') {
        Result.query({main: $scope.radioption, branch: $scope.selection[0], component: $scope.search }, function(results){
        $scope.results = results;
        $scope.buttonClickedAgain = true;
   }); 
   //if($scope.search) { 
     //$scope.buttonClickedAgain = true;
        //}
   }
$scope.buttonClicked = true;
};
```

You can check the below snippet where result will come after 5 seconds. But when you click the button, no results div hides immediately. You can try this with multiple clicks. If it does not work properly to you then its because of other code issue which throws error and check your browser console.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('TestController', function($scope, $timeout){
  $scope.fetchresults = function(){
     $scope.buttonClickedAgain = false;
   if($scope.value == 'showComponentSearch') {
        //$scope.results = Result.query({main: $scope.radioption, branch: $scope.selection[0],
           // $scope.search }); 
       $scope.results = [];
     $timeout(function() {
     var rnd = Math.random();
    
      if(rnd >= 0.5) {
        $scope.results = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}];
      }
     
   //if($scope.search) { 
     $scope.buttonClickedAgain = true;
       // }
       
       }, 5000);
    }
$scope.buttonClicked = true;
};
  
});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div  ng-controller="TestController" >
<form class="form-inline" name="myForm">
<div class="form-group" >
   <label class="radio-inline"> 
    <input name="sampleinlineradio" value="3" type="radio" ng-model="radioption"  
              ng-required="!radioption"> MAIN 1</label> 
   <label class="radio-inline"> 
   <input name="sampleinlineradio" value="1" type="radio"  ng-model="radioption"  >
        Main 2</label>

 <div ng-show="!radioption && buttonClicked">Please select one.</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <label ng-repeat="branch in branches"> 
   <input type="checkbox" name="selectedBranches[]" value="{{branch.value}}" 
          ng-model="branch.selected" ng-required="isOptionsRequired()" >
    {{branch.name}}</label>  

<div ng-show="isOptionsRequired() && buttonClicked">Please select one.</div>
</div>

<div>
<label class="searchlabel"> 
 <input type="radio" name="searchradio1" value="showComponentSearch"  ng-model="value"  
    ng-required="value == 'showComponentSearch'" > 
Search By Component</label> 
 <input type="text" name="comptext" ng-model="search" id="tags" 
    ng-required = "value == 'showComponentSearch' && search == 'comptext'" >

<div ng-show="value == 'showComponentSearch' && !search && buttonClicked">Please enter text before submit.</div>

<div>
<label class="searchlabel">
<input name="searchradio2" value="showDateRangeSearch" type="radio" ng-model="value" 
    ng-required="value == 'showDateRangeSearch'" > 
Search By Time</label>
</div>  </div>
<div ng-show="!value && buttonClicked">Please select one search option.</div>

<input type="button" ng-click="fetchresults()" value="submit" >
</form>

<div ng-show="buttonClicked">
  Records:
    <table>  <thead></thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr ng-show="results.length!=0"  ng-repeat="r in results">
       <td>{{r.id}}</td></tbody></table>
</div>

<div ng-show="buttonClickedAgain"> 
<span ng-show="results.length==0 ">No results.</span> 
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I have updated the code. You can check the below snippet where result will come after 5 seconds. But when you click the button, no results div hides immediately. You can try this with multiple clicks. If it does not work properly to you then its because of other code issue which throws error and check your browser console.

Comment: Okay i will check and get back to you.

Comment: I got the issue almost, Can you post your 'Result' service code?

Comment: Please check now.Have updated controller as you suggested i missed here. copy paste mistake

Comment: You can check the first snippet, the change is from the line `Result.query`. Also added `$scope.buttonClickedAgain = false;` before the `if` as suggested earlier

Comment: Both the timeout and this method worked. Why it works now in second method? what if i am using $q.all, will it work?

Comment: Don't use `$timeout`. This is to simulate the rest api call waiting to test the fix `$scope.buttonClickedAgain = false;`. Try the first method that's more similar to your case. You can use `$q.all` if you are more familiar with this. But the main thing is `true` should be set once the response received `$scope.buttonClickedAgain = true;` where in your old code, it has been set immediately that's why you saw the flickering.

Comment: @user3844782 I have invited you to the chat.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show` on the div . `ng-if` prevents the div from being rendered

`<div ng-show="buttonClickedAgain"> 
<span ng-show="results.length==0 ">No results.</span> 
</div>`